# recvfrom: warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ from ‘ssize_t’ may change the sign of the result

Tags: c

How can I fix the gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2 compiler warning

> warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ from ‘ssize_t’ may change the sign of
>   the result [-Wsign-conversion]    recv_len = recvfrom(my_socket, *buf,
>   MESSAGE_MAX_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &addr_len);

Code:

```
int my_socket;
struct sockaddr_storage remote_addr;
socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(remote_addr);

void
socket_listen(
        int (*callback )(),
        char ** buf)
{
  size_t recv_len;
  ...
  *buf = malloc(MESSAGE_MAX_LEN);
  recv_len = recvfrom(my_socket, *buf, MESSAGE_MAX_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &addr_len);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Use `ssize_t` for your `recv_len` :o

Comment: Rolled back your edit because the existing answer refers to the declaration of `recv_len` with incorrect type. If you edit it again, please make sure not to destroy this.

Answer (score 5):

The obvious fix: use the proper type, of course:

```
const ssize_t recv_len = recvfrom(...);
```

It's signed since it needs to be able to return a negative value (-1) to signal errors, see [the manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom):

> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred. The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.

Comment: nope: "error: assignment of read-only variable ‘recv_len’
   recv_len = recvfrom(my_socket, *buf, MESSAGE_MAX_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &addr_len);"

Comment: @Sam it's the correct answer and you edited your code snippet to be entirely unclear.